# Ruby on Rails : Manage array from client side in Rails application?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing a Rails 4 web application. In my Rails application View i have 2 forms . First form contains List of Employees where i can select employees and add to Second Form by clicking on ADD button . Second form also contains a button where i can remove employees from Second Form, all the removed employees will be moved back to first form.

Currently i achieving it like , when i click the add button in First form i will pass the selected employee data to controller through an Ajax call and return the same selected data to second form to display selected employees.

Is it possible to manage this from client side without making any call to Server.

Is there any gems available in Rails to achieve this.

I am using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.

Example : [Sample List Manipulation in Javascript](http://www.developergeekresources.com/examples/javascript/javascript-listbox_to_listbox.php)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible to do this on the client-side

---

**Javascript**

All I would do is replace your ajax calls with the on-page JS

Have used JQuery in this example (hope that's okay):

**http://jsfiddle.net/U443j/3/**

```
$(".move").on("click", "input", function() {
    var button = $(this).attr("id");
    var from = document.getElementById("FromLB");
    var to = document.getElementById("ToLB");

    if (button == "left") {
       move(to, from);
    }else{
       move(from, to);   
    }
});


function move(tbFrom, tbTo) 
{
 var arrFrom = new Array(); var arrTo = new Array(); 
 var arrLU = new Array();
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < tbTo.options.length; i++) 
 {
  arrLU[tbTo.options[i].text] = tbTo.options[i].value;
  arrTo[i] = tbTo.options[i].text;
 }
 var fLength = 0;
 var tLength = arrTo.length;
 for(i = 0; i < tbFrom.options.length; i++) 
 {
  arrLU[tbFrom.options[i].text] = tbFrom.options[i].value;
  if (tbFrom.options[i].selected && tbFrom.options[i].value != "") 
  {
   arrTo[tLength] = tbFrom.options[i].text;
   tLength++;
  }
  else 
  {
   arrFrom[fLength] = tbFrom.options[i].text;
   fLength++;
  }
}

tbFrom.length = 0;
tbTo.length = 0;
var ii;

for(ii = 0; ii < arrFrom.length; ii++) 
{
  var no = new Option();
  no.value = arrLU[arrFrom[ii]];
  no.text = arrFrom[ii];
  tbFrom[ii] = no;
}

for(ii = 0; ii < arrTo.length; ii++) 
{
 var no = new Option();
 no.value = arrLU[arrTo[ii]];
 no.text = arrTo[ii];
 tbTo[ii] = no;
}
}
```

This will allow you to move the items between form elements. The reason this is important is because it allows you to send the data to the controller as one data-set:

---

**Controller**

On my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U443j/3/), I have a `save` button

This can be tied to your Rails controller, allowing you to send your form data to your system

This will send your params hash like this:

```
params { "FromLB": ["value1", "value2"], "ToLB": ["value1", "value2"] }
```

The hash will be structured differently, but you'll get two sets of data, which you can then put into your db:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def action
   @from = params[:FromLB]
   @to = params[:ToLB]

   #Save the data-sets here
end
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.For Save button i can also use an Ajax call to server with the List i needed.right? because i don't want to reload the whole page again.

Comment: Sure - the big point is you need to send all the data to your controller, so you have both data-sets available in the backend. Currently, I believe you're sending single data-sets